# Customising UIActivity for UIActivityTypeMessage

Tags: ios, uiactivity

I'm sharing an image and its description text using `UIActivityType`. I need to share the URL of the image if I choose SMS sharing option. How can I do that? Currently I'm sharing the image and data to Facebook and Twitter. How to send the URL in case that SMS option is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share the image using SMS option in the same way that you are doing it with Facebook and Twitter.

The `activityType` for SMS is `UIActivityTypeMessage`. It is the built-in `activityType`.

So the only thing you need to do is provide image and image description as `activityItems` while creating your `UIActivityController`.

The code snippet is given below:

```
NSString *imageDescription = @"Image Description Goes Here";
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image_Name"];
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: imageDescription,image,nil];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```